# Report Manager Error: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I know there is many topics with this subject, but I already did my search (I went to the fifth page of my google search) and I still don't got the solution. I think my problem is different.

**Problem:**

I recently installed de Report Services 2008 in my computer and I configured with the default settings. When I try to acess the Report Manager(localhost/Reports) I get this error:

*The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.*

The content of the log file:

```
ui!ReportManager_0-7!450!06/14/2014-18:58:36:: e ERROR: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
ui!ReportManager_0-7!450!06/14/2014-18:58:36:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.GetSecureMethods()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.RSWebServiceWrapper.GetSecureMethods()

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.RSConnection.ValidateConnection()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.Global.SecureAllAPI()

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.EnsureHttpsLevel(HttpsLevel level)

   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ReportingPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
ui!ReportManager_0-7!450!06/14/2014-18:58:38:: e ERROR: Exception in ShowErrorPage: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg) at    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
library!WindowsService_3!14ac!06/14/2014-19:02:18:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()
library!WindowsService_3!14ac!06/14/2014-19:02:19:: i INFO: Cleaned 0 batch records, 0 policies, 0 sessions, 0 cache entries, 0 snapshots, 0 chunks, 0 running jobs, 0 persisted streams, 0 segments, 0 segment mappings.
library!WindowsService_3!14ac!06/14/2014-19:02:19:: i INFO: Call to CleanBatch() ends
```

**I already try:**

- Modify in the file "rsreportserver.config":
- Turn Off the Windows Firewall
- Turn Off the Antivirus
- Install and review IIS configuration
- Reboot computer

I realy dont know what is missing.

*Note:* The Report Service Web Service is working.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your settings by following :

[Link] [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725913(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725913%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Enable Firewall Exceptions for MS DTC

Comment: But if the problem is related to the firewall, when I disabled it wouldn't solve the problem?